# Infinity of R and C

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Why are two different concepts of infinity associated with the extended real line whereas just one concept of infinity is there in the extended complex plane? Considering the fact that any model of the complex plane contains a copy of the real numbers, shouldn't the same be said for the extended versions?

Comment: Do you mean that with the real numbers, we often talk of $+ \infty$ and $- \infty$ but with the complex numbers, we more often just talk of $\infty$?

Comment: In 2D, there is no natural ordering, $a<b$ is not available. All you can say is $|a|<|b|$.

Comment: @badjohn yes, precisely!

Comment: @Yves Daoust kindly read the second half of my question

Comment: @Advaita: I did. Please kindly understand my comment.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I am talking about isomorphic copies. Ordering needn't come into the picture. Further kindly define '2D' for by complex numbers I mean the minimal field extention of R  that contains a root of $x^2 +1$. I an not taking any particular model here.

Comment: There is no isomorphy between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.

Comment: One word: Order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that there are *many* ways to "assign a notion of infinity" to an object. For example, the projective plane has a whole *line* of "points at infinity" while the projective line has *only one* "point at infinity. Similarly, the [one point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) adds *exactly one* "point at infinity" to *any* geometric object (= [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology)) whatsoever.

That said, there is a meaningful sense in which $\mathbb{R}$ has more "infinities" than $\mathbb{C}$ - namely, when we talk about [**ends**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)). The key point here is that when we have $X\subseteq Y$, it does *not* follow that $Y$ has more ends than $X$.

---

Intuitively, when we go from $X$ to $Y$ we might wind up "gluing" ends together: while $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are "separated" in $\mathbb{R}$, in $\mathbb{C}$ we can get from one to the other by "going around" the whole plane. Slightly less crazily:

> Pick $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ "close to" $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively - say, $x=-10^{10}$ and $y=10^{10}$. To get from $x$ to $y$ inside $\mathbb{R}$, we have to go through $0$ - that is, to get from "near one infinity" to "near the other infinity" we have to go through "really not infinity."
>
> However, in $\mathbb{C}$ the situation is quite different: we can go from $(-10^{10}, 0)$ to $(10^{10}, 0)$ by going along the circle centered at $(0, 0)$ with radius $10^{10}$, and all along the way we stay "nearly infinite."

This is purely informal, and it may be more confusing than helpful - if so, ignore it, and even if it is helpful don't take it to seriously.

Comment: Thank you. The explanation was helpful.